# How to make update button worked inside table plugin | PHP and Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I've been working with my final project for bachelor degree and I have no more idea for this part and how to make it worked.

It worked yesterday with simply luck. But then I made a big mistake by deleted it and with no possibility to undo.

I'm pushing my limit since I'm new to php.

so I've been trying to update the "status" column.

I'm using a dataTable plugin.

The controllers, models, SQL update command are working fine. I think the big problem is on the PHP codes. With wrong placement of html form element, PHP foreach or PHP end tag

The problem is, I don't know how to make my update button work.

My button will only work when I delete one of my table header , the result my plugin was a mess. But when my plugin is stay on it's line, my button doesn't worked

please help? my head going nuts in 3 days without solution

Here's the codes

```
     <div class="dataTable_wrapper"> <!--table-responsive-->
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example"> <!--just class= table table-bordered edit-->
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Nama Depan</th>
                    <th>Nama Belakang</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Nomor HP</th>
                    <th>Alamat</th>
                    <th>Pesan</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Accept</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <?php $test123 = array("gradeA","gradeC","gradeU","gradeX");?>
                  <?php foreach($anggota as $p1){ ?>
              <form id="ADMIN" action="<?= base_url('administrasi/submit');?>" method="post">


                  <?php echo
                  "<tr class='".$test123[array_rand($test123)]."'>
                    <td>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id_dftr' value='$p1->id_dftr'>$p1->id_dftr
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='hidden' name='nm_dpn' value='$p1->nm_dpn'>$p1->nm_dpn
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='hidden' name='nm_blkng' value='$p1->id_dftr'>$p1->id_dftr
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='hidden' name='email' value='$p1->email'>$p1->email
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='hidden' name='nomorhp' value='$p1->nomorhp'>$p1->nomorhp
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='hidden' name='alamat' value='$p1->alamat'>$p1->alamat
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='hidden' name='pesan' value='$p1->pesan'>$p1->pesan
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='hidden' name='status' value='1'>$p1->status
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name='sbm' value='upd_user'>
                            <i class='fa fa-check'></i>Terima
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href='".base_url('administrasi/hps_dftr/'.$p1->id_dftr)."'>
                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>
                                <i class='fa fa-close'></i>Tolak
                           </button>
                        </a>  
                    </td>
                  </tr>";?>
             </form>   <!-- END FORM -->
          <?php }?>   <!-- END OF PHP -->
           </tbody>   <!-- END TABLE BODY -->
        </table>      <!-- END TABLE -->
     </div> <!-- /.dataTable_wrapper -->
```

Comment: Have you tried : `<th colspan="2">Accept</th>`?

Comment: You have 9 <th> and 10 <td> elements. Either they need to be same count or you need to span last <th> across two columns.

Comment: Add <th></th> after <th>Accept</th>.

Comment: I need to remove one of my table header to make the button work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying everyone! But I found the solution on my own lol

Bruh, Miracle does happen when you tired of trying.

```
<tbody>
  <?php $test123 = array("gradeA","gradeC","gradeU","gradeX");?>
      <?php foreach($anggota as $p1){ ?>

  <?php echo
  "<tr class='".$test123[array_rand($test123)]."'>";?>
        <form id="ADMIN" action="<?= base_url('administrasi/submit');?>" method="post">
<?php echo
    "<td>
        <input type='hidden' name='id_dftr' value='$p1->id_dftr'>$p1->id_dftr
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='hidden' name='nm_dpn' value='$p1->nm_dpn'>$p1->nm_dpn
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='hidden' name='nm_blkng' value='$p1->id_dftr'>$p1->id_dftr
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='hidden' name='email' value='$p1->email'>$p1->email
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='hidden' name='nomorhp' value='$p1->nomorhp'>$p1->nomorhp
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='hidden' name='alamat' value='$p1->alamat'>$p1->alamat
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='hidden' name='pesan' value='$p1->pesan'>$p1->pesan
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='hidden' name='status' value='1'>$p1->status
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name='sbm' value='upd_user'>
            <i class='fa fa-check'></i>Terima
        </button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href='".base_url('administrasi/hps_dftr/'.$p1->id_dftr)."'>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>
                <i class='fa fa-close'></i>Tolak
           </button>
        </a>  
    </td>";?>
        </form>   <!-- END FORM -->
<?php echo
"</tr>";?>
```